# Redirect using JS but trigger event incase tab closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, browser

I am looking to redirect to a third party website; I can achieve this easily using a **hyperlink or JS**.

However I want to be able to track if the window was closed or the page was unloaded after redirect. Is there any way that this can be achieved?

Perhaps *redirect using JS* and keep the function *running for 60 seconds after new page load* (I am not even sure if this is possible).

Can't do **iframes**, sorry.

Thanks : )

Comment: Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will help you to track the popup window. Inside onbeforeunload you can write your codes whatever you want to do.

```
<html>
<script>
function opener(){
    var open_new = window.open("","","width=600, height=600")
    open_new.onbeforeunload = function(){ alert('window closed')}
}
</script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="opener()">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. The function's context is in the parent window, so it would not be able to change anything in the popup window. But I guess this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to run JavaScript if you aren't the owner of the 3rd party website - at least not in the context of that site.

You can't redirect to another site and force the user to run your own JavaScript code there - that would introduce huge security problems.

You could, however, put content (like advertisements) on the 3rd party website to check if the user visits it. Or you can write a browser plugin and ask the user to isntall it.

If, however, you want to run JavaScript in your main window when the other, 3rd-party website is closed, you can use @VinothSd's answer.